# Win. 8.1: How to fix bug causing disassociated files, dysfunctional programs, corrupt system restores, etc

Tags: windows, windows-registry, crash

This morning, my computer (an Alienware Aurora R4, about 9 months old and running Windows 8.1) experienced its first crash. I don't quite remember the name of the error presented, but I can say with confidence that the string started with "DRIVER". Ends up that I had an Intel driver that was quite out of date (it has now been updated).

I have no logs of the crash itself (a program called "WhoCrashed" was also not able to detect any), but it was a BSOD. After shutting down, the computer completed the restarting process with no problems.

However, my computer has been left with issues, some of which I have listed here:

- Some files (namely, .scd files, which I open with Winrar) have dissociated themselves from the designated program that they open with. Furthermore, I an unable to set what program they do open with as a default -- not that the "open with" menu doesn't pop up, but that nothing happens when I select a program.
- The big, colorful tiles on the start screen -- forgive me, I really don't know what they're called and I utterly despise the phrase "app" -- fail to completely launch (note that they do start up, but don't finish doing so).
- There seems to be some blockages with the internet. Obviously, not blatant "we can't get to this webpage" blockages -- I'm typing this, after all -- but certain programs aren't able to connect to the internet.

After trying to do a system restore for what seems like 10 times from at least three different places, I've come to the conclusion that my computer thinks my restore points are corrupted. The error, coded "0x80070570" (yes, I have Googled it), says that a piece of registry cannot be moved.

An acquaintance of mine identified this whole issue to most likely be a registry error, so I ended up getting a good four or five registry cleaner programs -- none of them worked.

Oddly enough, this issue *has* happened before. Not the crash part, but all the problems. Previously, I have been able to fix this by going to the advanced start-up window and doing a system restore from there. (For some reason, restoring from my desktop in these previous instances ended up being unsuccessful.)

I've never been much of the computer repairman, and now I really don't have any ideas. Also, I'd rather not do a system refresh, as I would have a lot of programs to reinstall. If you managed to get through this whole thing and happen to have some ideas, I'd be grateful if you would share them.

If I've overlooked something obvious -- and I probably have -- you have my permission to call me an idiot (or your favorite synonym).

Comment: Could you please include some info on the crash? Did you get a BSOD? I would assume it rebooted fine since you were able to experience these issues? Are there any crash logs?